# recyclerview en fragment kotlin no carga los datos

Tags: recyclerview, fragment

La pregunta puede estar mal formualada por desconocimiento, estoy aprendiendo, agradecido de cualquier ayuda.

Al intentar montar el recycler view dentro de un fragment no consigo que me pase  los datos, pongo muestra de el codigo en kotlin

La parte del layout Manager me da error de contexto:

> rvRespuestas.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

```
var muroRespuestas = ArrayList<MuroRespuestas>()
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_respuestas,container,false)
    data()
    rvRespuestas.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rvRespuestas.adapter = MuroRespuestasAdapter(muroRespuestas)
}
fun data (){
    muroRespuestas.add(MuroRespuestas(R.drawable.ic_one,"prueba", "respuesta falsa" ))
    muroRespuestas.add(MuroRespuestas(R.drawable.ic_two,"prueba 1", "respuesta falsa 1 " ))
    muroRespuestas.add(MuroRespuestas(R.drawable.ic_three,"prueba 3", "respuesta falsa 2" ))
}
```

---

Añado el error LOGCAT, no consigo entender, muchas gracias por la ayuda.
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

> Task :app:buildInfoDebugLoader
>   Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
>   e: C:\Users\oscar.lluch\AndroidStudioProjects\AlphaVaccines\app\src\main\java\olluch\m\alphavaccines\RespuestasActivity.kt: (23, 58): Type mismatch: inferred type is RespuestasActivity but Context! was expected
>
> Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

  > Compilation error. See log for more details
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Answer (score 0):

El error que indicas se debe a que esta linea tiene un error, indicando que hay un error en el `contexto`.

> rvRespuestas.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager("this")

El contexto que debes usar para instanciar tu [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager), debe ser `this` o `getApplicationContext()` y no "this".

```
   rvRespuestas.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

---

También puedes declarar el contexto a usar en tu LinearLayoutManager de esta forma:

```
val activity = activity as Context

rvRespuestas.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
```

Comment: Hola cambié el contexto por this sin comillas pero me sigue dandi el mismo error

Comment: Que error se muestra en el LogCat, trata de aportar esa información.

Comment: Añado el LOGCAT pero la verdad es que soy incapaz de ver el error, más allá del error de Contexto :(

Comment: geacias, revisa la actualización.

Comment: me sigue dando error, puede que el error vaya por el tab, me explico estoy intentando instanciar el recycler view en unfragment no en el ActivityMain, lo que no se es que contexto tengo que utilizar en el fragment, gracias por adelantado